# Infopath 2010: Display SP choice column in text box with spaces or commas

Tags: infopath, choice-field

So, I've got this Infopath 2010 form. I've got my data connections and rules setup for cascading drop downs, where the final selection (job title) populates a text box (Software) with a list of programs. The text box is populated by an SP choice column.

It works, but there is no spaces or commas between the values! All the values run together like a single string.